# How can I get MongoDB results into an asynchronous callback

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Is it possible to get the results of this query into the node var object "data"? The correct console.log(results) appears in the console but the results is not retuned to the data variable.

```
var Metric = require('../metric');
var gViews = Object.create(Metric.prototype);
gViews.name = 'g_ref';
gViews.initialData = 0;

gViews.increment = function(results) {



var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var server = new mongodb.Server("127.0.0.1", 27017, {});

new mongodb.Db('xxxx', server, {}).open(function (error, client) {
    client.collection('xxxx_1', function(err, collection) {
        collection.insert({ref_domain:g}, function(err, docs) {
            collection.find({ref_domain: /g/}).count(function(err, results) {
                console.log(results);

            });
        });
    });
});
this.data;
};




module.exports = gViews;
```

Comment: You don't ever set the value -- so how would it be set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to set it.

```
var Metric = require('../metric');
var gViews = Object.create(Metric.prototype);
gViews.name = 'g_ref';
gViews.initialData = 0;

gViews.increment = function(results) {
    var mongodb = require('mongodb');
    var server = new mongodb.Server("127.0.0.1", 27017, {});

    new mongodb.Db('xxxx', server, {}).open(function (error, client) {
        client.collection('xxxx_1', function(err, collection) {
            collection.insert({ref_domain:g}, function(err, docs) {
                collection.find({ref_domain: /g/}).count(function(err, results) {
                    gViews.data = results;
                });
            });
        });
    });
};

module.exports = gViews;
```

Comment: Mr. Ford, Thank you so much! I have been struggling with this for quite some, time chasing it as if it was an async problem. This worked perfectly.  Thank you again!

Comment: Glad I could help. If you're interested in flattening out some of that nasty *nested callback hell* you should check out a library called [async](https://npmjs.org/package/async). It's [waterfall](https://npmjs.org/package/async#waterfall) function would let you flatten out those nested callbacks so they are easier to read. Your script could look [like this instead](https://gist.github.com/Chevex/7299157) :)